# want to get currently logged user's id (using django-registration )

Tags: django, django-registration, user-profile, django-forms

I'm using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) for registration and login purpose. My `Models` and `Forms.py` are working fine. The problem is I want to store the currently logged user's `id` in the `user` field of the following `Model`:

```
MALE = 1
FEMALE = 2
SEX_CHOICES = (
    (MALE,'Male'),
    (FEMALE,'Female'),
)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #user = models.IntegerField() # update : Changed to ForeignKey. 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices = SEX_CHOICES,null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

My `ModelForm`:

```
 class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        widgets = {'language': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

Update 2: Here is my `view`:

```
def some_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()
else:
    form = UserProfileForm()
```

Update: I can get currently logged in user's using `{{ user.id }}` in template. But now How do i pass this `id` to `user field`?

Comment: Well, you can access current user through an instance of [django.http.HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) class which is available in the view (usually as argument named `request` for standard function views or found in the `self.request` attribute for Class-based views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in you view you can access the currently logged `user` *via* `request.user`.

Make this user `initial` data in your `Form` :

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    logged_user = request.user
    initial = {'user': logged_user}
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
    # Here your logical code
    # ...
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

And if you are using a `ModelForm`:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    logged_user = request.user
    form = MyUserProfileModelForm(
                 request.POST or None,\
                 instance=logged_user.get_profile())
    # Here your logical code
    # ...
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

Note: `get_profile()` is a `OneToOneField` and may raise a `DoesNotExist` exception if your database is screwed (which may happen if you have tried different things here).

Comment: it worked. But If i edit form then this code inserting new row into table.

Comment: It should be `MyForm(instance=request.user.get_profile()`, data=request.POST or None)`

Comment: @sdolan thanks But another issue `You need to set AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings`

Comment: @no_access: So, in your `settings.py` add `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = your_app.UserProfile`

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not see your were using a ModelForm. In this case using `instance` parameter make sense to link your form with your `user_profile` instance. You don't need to use `initial` because all your fields will be prepopulated with the instance value.